# How many 2560x1600 resolution monitors can Eyefinity support?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon, eyefinity

How many 2560x1600 resolution monitor can Eyefinity support? AMD states it can support up to 6 monitors but they don't state the resolution.

Comment: An eyefinite amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 7680 x 3200 resolution grouping three displays wide x two displays
>   high with landscape orientation using 2560x1600 display resolution for
>   each monitor (24.6 megapixel resolution)

**The [ATI Eyefinity tech brief](http://www.amd.com/us/documents/ati_eyefinity_technology_brief.pdf) explicitly mentions this setup, so you should be good :)** Just make sure you have enough displayport outputs.
Edit: And [here's that resolution running on a single card back in 2009](http://www.anandtech.com/show/2833), if you wanna see that.

---

And I can see your other SU questions have related to this, so here: the easiest way to get an absurdly high resolution running off 1 card is probably a 7870 with 6 dp outputs, [like this one](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814131474). Not that cheap for a gaming card, but very cheap compared to the pro stuff... **and, actually, really cheap compared to the cost of 6 WQXGA monitors anyway. Or, for that matter, one WQXGA monitor.**

---

And here are the possible layouts, screenshot of [the Eyefinity setup page](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/amd-eyefinity-technology/how-to/Pages/set-up.aspx). (Oh, there's also a 5x1 vertical resolution that was just added, for 8000*2560 with these monitors, but it's not in the setup page yet.)
[image: Eyefinity layout]

Edit: For a non-gamer (programmer, perhaps?), there isn't really an advantage to Eyefinity, and you don't have to worry about layout really, so **you could actually put 6 monitors side-by-side if you wanted, or any other layout, just as separate monitors instead of a single hires display**. But this is a bit out of the question scope.

> Up to 6 displays supported
>   Independent resolutions, refresh rates, color controls, and video overlays

[source](http://powercolor.com/us/products_features.asp?id=415)

Comment: But, will this card support 6 2560x1600 monitors? If yes, then Eyefinity can support 6 2560x1600 monitors?

Comment: Yes, it should. The first part answers that.

Comment: So, Eyefinity can support a max of 8192x8192 using a max number of 6 monitors. If this is correct, I can't add 6 2560x1600 monitors one next to other because the resolution will be (2560x6 = 15300) 15300x1600 and 15300 is way off 8192. But I can add up and 3 down having a total resolution of (2560x3 = 7680) 7680x7680 witch is withing the limits of EyeFinity. Correct?

Comment: Right, you can't do 6w*1h 15360*1600. You can do 3w*2h 7680x3200, as well as the just-added 5w*1h sideways 8000*2560.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Something final: the screenshots you posted have numbers on the displays 1, 2, 3, 4. What do those numbers mean?

Comment: All the monitors with the same number are configured as one enormous screen to Windows, so for example if you fullscreen your browser it'll fill them all. Also, this allows bezel correction for gaming. The 2,3,4 monitors are separate ones like any other multi-monitor setup.

Comment: I just don't know how to thank you...

Comment: Oh and I guess there is no way to have 6 completely different monitors?

Comment: Oh, there's that option too, it's just not an "Eyefinity" display.

Comment: Sorry for asking a billion questions... What if it stops to be an Eyefinity display?

Comment: Windows will then see 6 separate monitors (I think it supports plenty more than that), and you can arrange them however you wish just like a standard multimonitor setup. Each will have a start bar and all that. Oh, assuming you're a Windows guy.

Comment: Then what benefit Eyefinity provides over 6 interdependent monitors? (other than gaming related features) edit: OK, http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/showthread.php?t=148962 found it. But, are you sure I can support 6 monitors independently without Eyfinity?

Comment: Well, for one windows 7 only results in one task bar if you use extended desktop. With eyefinity it sees all monitors all fewer but larger displays. So you can have one start bar stretching across several monitors.  Or run one 'full screen' application acros multiple monitors.